# attaching generated pdf to form and send in phpmailer

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer

I am able to generate pdf and send that generated pdf as attachment to entered email-id. But i want something like, when i click on email it should generate pdf and open a form with user entry fields like To, Message, Subject.... etc... And that generated pdf should show as attachment

Now when click on email it will open an user entry form then when i click on send , it will generate pdf and send that pdf.

Here is my code

My html form

```
<form method="post" action="send_mail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="formSep">
<label class="req">To Email: </label>
<input type="text" name="email" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <select name="email"><option value="">Select one</option><?php $s1 = mysql_query("select * from lead_contact where company_id=".$company."");
while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($s1)) { $name = $r1['firstname'].' '.$r1['lastname'];
$cid = $r1['con_id'];
$cemail = $r1['email']; ?>
<option value="<?php echo $cemail;?>"><?php echo $name;?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<?php echo $order_id; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" />

<div class="formSep">
<label class="req">Subject</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" /></div>

<div class="formSep">
<label class="req"> Message</label>


<div class="w-box" id="n_wysiwg">
<div class="w-box-header">
<h4>WYSIWG Editor</h4>
</div>
<div class="w-box-content cnt_no_pad">
<textarea name="message" id="wysiwg_editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="formSep">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info" /></div>

</form>
```

send_email.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit'] == "Submit")
{

    $id = $_POST['order_id'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    include("../admin_auth.php");


include("../connect.php");
require('invoice.php');

$pdf = new PDF_Invoice( 'P', 'mm', 'A4' );
$pdf->AddPage();


//MY PDF CODE GOES HERE

$pdf->Output("D:/wamp/www/folder/uploads/".$id.".pdf","F");

$path = "D:/wamp/www/folder/uploads/".$id.".pdf";
require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("class.smtp.php");



$to = $_POST['email'];
$from = $_SESSION['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "hostname";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'user';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->From=$_SESSION['email'];
$mail->FromName=$_SESSION['name'];
$mail->Sender=$email;


$mail->AddAddress($to);



$mail->AddBCC("test@test.com");
$mail->AddAttachment($path, '', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
$mail->Subject = $subject;

$mail->CharSet="windows-1251";
$mail->CharSet="utf-8";

$mail->IsHTML(true);


$mail->Body = $message;


if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;;
}
else
{
echo "Email Sent!";
}
}
?>
```

I am not getting how to get the form with pdf attached, so that user can write in the body , add cc and sent email

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
$path = "D:/wamp/www/folder/uploads/".$id.".pdf";

$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');    //Cc stands for carbon copy
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com'); //Bcc stands for blind carbon copy

$mail->AddAttachment($path, '', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
```

**NOTE:** FOR REFERENCE OF PHP MAILER :

**Check This:** https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

> **Cc** stands for carbon copy which means that whose address appears after
>   the Cc: header would receive a copy of the message. Also, the Cc
>   header would also appear inside the header of the received message.
>
> **Bcc** stands for blind carbon copy which is similar to that of Cc except
>   that the Email address of the recipients specified in this field do
>   not appear in the received message header and the recipients in the To
>   or Cc fields will not know that a copy sent to these address.

Comment: I think you are not getting what extactly i am looking for!. When i click on email, pdf should generate and a html editor with form  should open with pdf attached. In that user should be able to write or to cc etc then he will click on send

Comment: Then you have to write the code of that form first. .. That Open ... Then in php you have to write the same code if isset the email .. button

Comment: Form is opening now, but pdf is not getting attached. Thats what my question is all about

Comment: As per I post in my ans.  Check

Answer (score 0):

It really helps if you get your basic PHP syntax right. This is just meaningless:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($path, '', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf');
```

All you need is this:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($path);
```

It will take care of the rest for you.